# Why does the std::size on an array passed by value do not work?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17, pass-by-reference

Why does the `std::size()` do not work on a statically allocated array passed by value?

```
void print_elemTab(int tab[])
{
   // ...
   int size = std::size(tab); //error 
   // ...
}

void test_tab()
{
   const int    TAB_SIZE = 5;
   int          tab[TAB_SIZE] = {};
   // ...
   cout << std::size(tab) << std::endl; //print 5
   print_elemTab(tab);
   // ...
}
```

I am printing the size and then I am passing the `tab` in the sub-function `print_elemTab()` where I am using `std::size()` again.

I get *no matching function* error, so I wonder why `std::size()` works the first time in `test_tab()` and not in `print_elemTab()`

Do I have to pass it by reference? And so how do I make it but for an array of any length?

Or do I have to make it in another way because of something that I am not aware of?

Comment: In a function parameter list, `int tab[]` means exactly the same thing as `int *tab`. So you're passing a pointer rather than an array.

Comment: Alternatively change to `void print_elemTab(int tab[], std::size_t n)` and call with `print_elemTab(tab, std::size(tab))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array designators used in expressions are implicitly converted (with rare exceptions as for example using them in the `sizeof` operator)  to pointers to their first elements.

So in this call

```
print_elemTab(tab);
```

the argument expression has the type `int *`.

On the other hand, a function parameter having an array type is adjusted by the compiler to pointer to the element type of the array.

So for example these function declarations

```
void     print_elemTab(int tab[]);
void     print_elemTab(int tab[5]);
void     print_elemTab(int tab[100]);
```

declare the same one function and are equivalent to the following declaration

```
void     print_elemTab(int *tab);
```

You nay even include all these declarations in your program though the compiler can issue a message that there are redundant declarations.

Hence within the function you are dealing with a pointer of the type `int *`. And `sizeof( int * )` is usually equal to `4` or `8` depending on the used system.

If you have such a declaration you should change it specifying a second parameter that will keep the number of elements in the passed array like

```
void     print_elemTab(int *tab, size_t n );
```

And the function can be called like

```
print_elemTab(tab, std::size( tab ) );
```

Another approach is to pass the array by reference. In this case you should declare a template function for example like

```
template <size_t N>
void     print_elemTab( int ( &tab )[N] );
```

Within the function you can either directly use the template parameter `N` as the number of elements in the array. Or you can apply the same standard C++ function `std::size` to the array.

Or the function can be even more general declared with a second template type parameter like

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
void     print_elemTab( T ( &tab )[N] );
```

Another approach is to declare the function like

```
template <typename Container>
void     print_elemTab( Container &container );
```

In this case you also may apply the standard function `std::size` to the parameter container.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I have to pass it by reference? And so how do I make it but for any
> array of any length?

**Yes**, passing it by reference would be one option.

```
template<std::size_t n>
void print_elemTab(int (&tab)[N]) // const int (&tab)[N], if the elements won't be modified
{
    std::cout << N << "\n"; // where you can directly get the size `N`
}
```

---

Or like simple templated function as follows

```
template<typename T>
void  print_elemTab(T& tab)// const T& tab, if the elements won't be modified
{
   const auto size = std::size(tab);
   std::cout << size << "\n";
}
```

---

Another option is to deduce the array to its actual type. In your case, the `tab` has the type `int[5]`. The compiler can deduce to its actual type(other than decaying to pointer) if you *[perfectly forward](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/perfect-forwarding-and-universal-references-in-c)* via a template function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<typename T>
void  print_elemTab(T&& tab)
{
   const auto size = std::size(tab);  // now you can do std::size() on the int[size]
   std::cout << size << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to pass it by reference because it's decayed to a pointer on passing it to your function. and to make the function accept any size I suggest to use a function template as follows

```
#include <iostream>

template<size_t n>
void print_elemTab(int (&tab)[n])
{
    int size = std::size(tab);
    std::cout << size << "\n";// or just  std::cout << n; and ignore the previous line 
}
    
void test_tab() {
    const int TAB_SIZE = 5;
    int tab[TAB_SIZE] = {};
    std::cout << std::size(tab) << std::endl; //print 5
    print_elemTab(tab);
    
}
    
int main(){
    test_tab();
}
```

Comment: Might want to mention that a templated function is a family of functions, not a single function that works on all arrays- if code calls `print_elemTab()` with an array of five `int` and, somewhere else, with an array of three `int`, two distinct functions (for which code is generated) will be called. This can cause larger executables unless the compiler does a good job of inlining (which not all compilers do). Not a showstopper, but something to be aware of when using this technique. Also, in your example, using `std::size(tab)` is unnecessary, since it will always be equal to `n`.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the comment I've updated the answer but I suppose the OP already knows about templates.